# XPages csjs pass a variable into a function?

Tags: javascript, variables, xpages, client-side

On a button click, I'm calling a function in client side JavaScript.

```
doIt("TEST");
```

"TEST" is just the ID of label on my XPage.
In the function, I want to use the variable I passed as an ID. Something like:

```
function doIt(item){
 alert(dojo.query("[id$=':item']").innerHTML);
}
```

OR

```
function doIt(item){
 val = XSP.getElementById("#{id:item}").innerHTML;
 alert(val);
}
```

I have also tried using this, which gives undefined:

```
val = dojo.query("[id$=':" + item + "']").innerHTML;
alert(val);
```

If I hard code the ID name like so, then I get the correct innerHTML of the element with the ID "TEST":

```
val = XSP.getElementById("#{id:TEST}").innerHTML;
alert(val);
```

Where is my syntax wrong when trying to write this very simple line of code used the passed variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to call your function with the complete id:

```
doIt("#{id:Test}")
```

and to use it in your function

```
function doIt(item){
    alert(dojo.byId(item).innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the "onclick" client-event in the button, (inside XPage or CC), the client Ids can be computed, so you should put there something like this:

```
doIt("#{id:Test}");   // << "#{id:Test}" is computed in the server-side and the final client ID is sent to the browser
```

Then, in your cjs library (cjs libraries are not "evaluated" before sending to the client, so here you cannot use "#{id:Test}" expressions) you should have something like:

```
function doIt(idElement) {
    var domElem = dojo.byId(idElement);  // << here you get the element
}
```